# Want matching words using existed regular expression only

Tags: regex, angularjs

I want to get matched words in angular js by comparing with string using below regular expression only. Means if any one or more words of the expression are there in string i have to get those matched words.

`ABC|DFG|KLO|UIO|KL|WER|GHJFFF|GROUP|KLO\\w+|SERTG\\w+|KLP|IOO|SDDD|ERT|KLO|FGH|IOPLK|ASDFGHJ\\w+|ERTYUIOPLK|/\\w+`

I tried like following

`var res = punctuationLess.match(/INC|LLC|LTD|LLP|NV|LP|INDUSTRY|GROUP|COMPAN\\w+|CORPORAT\\w+|CORP|CO|PLC|PTY|GMBH|AG|PPLC|HOLDING\\w+|UNIVERSITY|/\\w+/g);`

but not working. syntax error coming.

Answer (score 0):

I put the regex in an [online regex checker](http://regex101.com/) and it didn't like the forward slash at the 4th character from the end.

I'd suggest removing that to leave

ABC|DFG|KLO|UIO|KL|WER|GHJFFF|GROUP|KLO\w+|SERTG\w+|KLP|IOO|SDDD|ERT|KLO|FGH|IOPLK|ASDFGHJ\w+|ERTYUIOPLK|\w+

Answer (score 0):

```
INC|LLC|LTD|LLP|NV|LP|INDUSTRY|GROUP|COMPAN\\w+|CORPORAT\\w+|CORP|CO|PLC|PTY|GMBH|AG|PPLC|HOLDING\\w+|UNIVERSITY|\\w+
```

You can try this.Your delimiter `/` was before `\\w+` at the end.